# Getting the hivecontext from a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I am creating a hivecontext instead of sqlcontext to create adtaframe

```
val conf=new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-cluster")
val context=new SparkContext(conf)
//val sqlContext=new SQLContext(context)
val hiveContext=new HiveContext(context)
val data=Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).map(x=>(x.toLong,x+1,x+2.toDouble)).toDF("ts","value","label")
//outdta is a dataframe
data.registerTempTable("df")
//val hiveTest=hiveContext.sql("SELECT * from df where ts < percentile(BIGINT ts, 0.5)")
val ratio1=hiveContext.sql("SELECT percentile_approx(ts, array (0.5,0.7)) from df")
```

I need to get the exact hive context from ratio1 and not again create a hivecontext from the povidedsql context in the dataframe, I don't know why spark don't give me a hivecontext from dataframe and it just gives sqlcontext.

Comment: Have you considered accpeting my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `HiveCOntext`, then the runtime-type of `df.sqlContext` is `HiveContext` (`HiveContext` is a subtype of `SQLContext`), therefore you can do:

```
val hiveContext = df.sqlContext.asInstanceOf[HiveContext]
```